# Access bitlocker drive in external USB

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption

I have a drive with a bitlocker encryption. Because it was to small I upgraded my computer with a new drive.

Now I want to use that drive as an external USB-disk.

On another computer, the drive isn't even recognized at all, in the computer where the disk has been, the disk is displayed as "offline" because of a "signature conflict" (I guess this is, because the internal drive has the same signature)

All I want to do is to wipe that disk completely and use it as an external drive. What can be done?

Comment: You should have disabled bitlocker then enabled it again as an external drive, I suspect your original pc, had a TPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open cmd, write Diskpart - popup comes so click "yes"
now you type

> write "list disk"
>   if they show you a disk 1 - so it means it is your usb drive/ or you must check which one is the usb drive.
>   (dont format the disk 0/ its your main OS system)
>   "select disk 1" (to select your USB )
>   "clean"
>   "create partition primary"
>   "select partition 1"
>   "active"
>   "format fs=fat32 quick"
>   "assign"
>   "exit"

done.
should to work